# Redhawk Vita49 Segmentation Fault with CentOS7

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm running Redhawk 2.0.4 on CentOS 7.3.1611.  I compiled and installed Vita49Libraries (3.0.0), SourceVita49 (3.0.1), and SinkVita49 (3.0.1) from source.  When I drag a SourceVita49 or SinkVita49 component onto the sandbox in the IDE I get the following errors:

> Error while waiting for component SinkVITA49_1 to launch.
>   Component terminated while waiting to launch.
>   SinkVITA49_1 Terminated with exit code SIGSEGV (11)
>
> Error while waiting for component SourceVITA49_1 to launch.
>   Component terminated while waiting to launch.
>   SourceVITA49_1 Terminated with exit code SIGSEGV (11)

Looking on GitHub [here](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/VITA49Libraries/issues/3) I see an issue about a "crash" of the Vita49Libraries under Fedora24.

Can you confirm that this issue on Fedora24 is the same segmentation faults I'm seeing?

Does anyone know a way to get the VITA49 components to run under CentOS7?

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be the same issue as reported in the referenced github issue. You can replicate with the following steps via docker:

```
# Run the redhawk 2.0.4 container for el7 with escalated privileges so we can get a core dump and trace it
[ylb@axios ~] docker run -it --rm --privileged --cap-add CAP_PTRACE  axios/redhawk:2.0-el7

# Clone and build 
[redhawk@4d1172e29587] git clone https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/VITA49Libraries.git
[redhawk@4d1172e29587] pushd VITA49Libraries/cpp/
[redhawk@4d1172e29587] ./reconf && ./configure && make -j && sudo make install && popd

[redhawk@4d1172e29587] git clone https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/SinkVITA49.git
[redhawk@4d1172e29587] pushd SinkVITA49/cpp/
[redhawk@4d1172e29587] ./reconf && ./configure && make -j && sudo make install && popd

# Set core dump size to unlimited.
[redhawk@4d1172e29587] ulimit -c unlimited

# Hop into python and launch component
[redhawk@4d1172e29587] python
>>> from ossie.utils import sb
>>> snk = sb.launch('rh.SinkVITA49')

# It will crash
[redhawk@4d1172e29587 ~]$ ls
core.4287  SinkVITA49  VITA49Libraries

# Install gdb and trace out the issue
[redhawk@4d1172e29587 ~]$ sudo yum install gdb
[redhawk@4d1172e29587 ~]$ gdb /var/redhawk/sdr/dom/components/rh/SinkVITA49/cpp/SinkVITA49 core.4287

# leads us to

...
#1  0x00007f254971204e in std::string::assign(std::string const&) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007f254c802055 in operator= (__str="", this=0x7f254ca396f0 <_leapSecondsFile>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:547
#3  _init () at vrt_src/cpp_src/vrt/lib/VRTConfig.cc:84
#4  0x00007f254c802f25 in vrt::VRTConfig::getLeapSecondsFile () at vrt_src/cpp_src/vrt/lib/VRTConfig.cc:141
#5  0x00007f254c7ae0b5 in vrt::LeapSeconds::getDefaultInstance () at vrt_src/cpp_src/vrt/lib/LeapSeconds.cc:195
#6  0x00007f254c7fad3d in vrt::TimeStamp::TimeStamp (this=0x7f254ca39640 <vrt::TimeStamp::NO_TIME_STAMP>, tsiMode=<optimized out>, tsfMode=vrt::FractionalMode_None, tsi=<optimized out>, tsf=9223372036854775808, sr=nan(0x8000000000000))
    at vrt_src/cpp_src/vrt/lib/TimeStamp.cc:84
#7  0x00007f254c781d35 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535) at vrt_src/cpp_src/vrt/lib/TimeStamp.cc:28
...

# Which is the static initialization within the TimeStamp file.
```

While I haven't tried it, I imagine running the same steps with the el6 container "docker run -it --rm --privileged --cap-add CAP_PTRACE  axios/redhawk:2.0" would not core dump.

Comment: See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order, _leapSecondsFile is a std::string which is very tricky in static initialization. CentOS 7 probably has a newer compiler which just generates some different initialization order.

Comment: Thanks for reproducing this on your side.  I'll just stay with CentOS 6 for now.